# What does $\{0_\mathbb{R}\}$ mean

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I was told to suppose that $x \in \mathbb{R}\setminus \{0_\mathbb{R}\}$. What does $\{0_\mathbb{R}\}$ refer to?

Comment: Absent description of some exotic notation, the set containing exactly the additive neutral element of $\Bbb R$ (id est, the singleton of the usual zero).

Comment: The context in which you found this, framed in a block quote, would be very nice.

Comment: I would assume, but not take it as a certainty, that $0_{\mathbb R}$ refers to the real number $0$.  The sub R would be to distinguish it from the identity element of other groups or rings or fields (although way that was considered nesc. is unclear to me).  I would assume the brackets refer to a set with 0 as a single element and the slash means "set minus".  Thus "let x be a non-zero real".  Or so I would assume.  It's not a certainty.

Comment: For example if you where considering some ring homomorphism between some other ring $X$ and the ring $\mathbb{R}$ of real numbers, you could use the notation $0_\mathbb{R}$ to emphasize that you mean the zero in $\mathbb{R}$. The zero of the other ring could be $0_X$ then.

Answer (score 1):

$0_\mathbb R$ is the zero element.

$\{0_\mathbb R\}$ refers to the set of all things which are the zero element in your ring $R$.

Saying $x \in \mathbb R \setminus \{0_\mathbb R\}$ means your ring $\mathbb R$ minus the zero-element.

Comment: ah right, does this mean the same as "x can take any value in $\mathbb{R}$ excluding 0"?

Comment: $0_\mathbb{R}$ refers to the zero element. $\{ 0_\mathbb{R} \}$ refers the set whose only object is the zero element.

Comment: "ah right, does this mean the same as "x can take any value in R excluding 0"?"  That would be how I would interpret it and what this answer is saying, yes.

Comment: Yes, this means that x can be any real number except 0 in this scenario.